# How to connect NodeJS backend with NextJS, how to set proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, mern

I am developing Social media app using NextJS & Node. I have created seperate backend using NodeJS. Now I want to connect NextJS frontend with Node backend. but when i set the "proxy": `"http://localhost:8080/"` inside package.json file that is inside my nextjs app. but still it's not fetching the API.

Comment: you can simply do some http request(using axios or got for instance) from your Next.js app to your nodejs app.

Comment: Pls how did you accomplish this? I am also facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, I don't think Next.js use `proxy` in `package.json`. If you want to achieve how `proxy` works in Create-React-App, you need to assign `http://localhost:8080/` to an environmental variable in `next.config.js`.

You can access your base URL from when you try to make HTTP call like `` fetch(`${DEV_URL_HOST}/users`) ``

***References***

[Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)